# I get a cross-origin error when making a HTTP requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, http, cross-domain

I have requests that are valid when I am making requests from browser , but through the Angular 9 app I get a 401 error.
This is the header from chrome:

```
    Request URL: http://localhost:1234/api/Common/GetMy_List
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 6069
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 12:55:39 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:1234
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36
```

I have an angular 9 project with proxy.conf.json file that declared in package.json.
the file contain this lines:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1234",
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In server side there is an asp.net api with this lines in global.asax:

```
 public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string httpOrigin = Request.Params["HTTP_ORIGIN"];
            if (httpOrigin == null) httpOrigin = "*";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpOrigin);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                var httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
                httpApplication.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }
```

In the web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />  
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />  
  </system.webServer>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ImpersonateBehaviour">
          <clientCredentials>
            <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/xxx.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonateBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="Service1Ref.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: someone here ??

Comment: Try adding this header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *` - does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `Application_BeginRequest` to this. When I try using yours it fails on my code. The below code works.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Token");
         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
         HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that I can to enter Application_BeginRequest but not into my function in the controller,which means CORES privilege issue.

so In the IIS, I added anonymous authentication and now I can make requests of GET/POST and others.

In IIS choose your site in Sites then dowble click on Authentications categoty, then=>:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Browser allows any http request to the origin ( url where your http session started ). In single page applications we usually load the DOM which intern makes additional XHRs to a new domain (usually a new web app/rest api) . This is considered as a security flaw and all of the reputable and modern browsers stopped supporting this behavior.

To mitigate this you need a proxy in origin domain. All of the request to get data should pass through it.

In angular you can :

1. Configure the server to send the appropriate CORS headers
2. Configure Angular CLI proxy

I suggest using angular CLI proxy rather than adding CORS configuration.

Comment: In my answer I wrote that I declared proxy.conf.json. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes and what is your API url? I guess its in local host and not on same port as your web. Then you may have to change it to "target": "http://<<your web api url>>"

if you have api deployed in several endpoints, there is a way to handle that too. Please see : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries

Comment: the API url: http://localhost:1234. Please read my code